# Jquery-Datatables re-initializing on restroration visits

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks, jquery-datatables-rails

I am using rails 6 app which has turbolinks enabled. I have used jquery-data table on several pages. My issue is when I try to use browser' back and forth buttons, turbolinks performs restoration visit and my jquery-data table is re-initialized. I dont know what it is.

[image]